# Prevent 180 degree flip iOS Cordova

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I am using this plugin https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation for orientation and I'm doing this in config.xml file `<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />`. This prevents it flipping to landscape mode, but can still file 180 degrees on my iPhone. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable this by unchecking the `upside down` orientation in Xcode.[image]

Comment: I actually had portrait, landscape left and right checked. Not upside down. So the answer is to just check portrait. I know that's what you're saying. But I felt it would be important to make that clear, since you wouldn't think 
 checking landscape left/right would affect its ability to flip 180 deg.

Comment: This is not a good solution, when working with Cordova apps you should never make changes in the Xcode project. The settings you manually change can be reset

Comment: Well what's the alternative then?

Answer (score 1):

the orientation preferences are not for the `cordova-plugin-orientation`, those are regular cordova preferences as as you say, portrait allows both portrait options, regular portrait and upside down.

For only allowing regular portrait you have to use `portrait-primary`, but not as a preference.

As you are using the `cordova-plugin-orientation`, you have to use it's api to lock the screen rotation, so use this after device ready fires

`window.screen.orientation.lock('portrait-primary');`